# Optionally show or hide a field on google sheets sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Learning to write Google scripts. I am trying to determine if one sidebar form can be used for both creating or updating an item value pair.

When used for update the form would display the item and have a form field to change the value.

Whereas for create the form would have two form fields, one for the item and one for the value.

Wondering if there is a way to embed a script within the HTML file and display the item if update or display a textfield if create.

Not sure if I can pass an argument to HTML and use it within the embedded script.

Here is the HTML file. the first field is a selector. For an update I want to optionally replace the selector with a line of text that has the item populated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
  function loadFoods() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      var foodSelect = document.getElementById("food");
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = "";
      option.text = "";
      foodSelect.appendChild(option);
      ar.forEach(function(item,index) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item[0];
        option.text = item[0];
        foodSelect.appendChild(option);
      });
    }).getList();
  };
</script>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <style>
input[type="text"] {
    width: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
  <body>
  <div>
  <select id="food" placeholder="food" ></select>
  <script>loadFoods();</script>
  <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="amount in gms">
  <button onclick="sendResponse()">&#129746</button>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Feel free to make a copy of this sheet, there is script and HTML for a sidebar Sheet sizer and should get you going in the right direction.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=15942834

Comment: Kindly edit your question and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response to my question. I looked at the spreadsheet. unfortunately I was not able to see the script itself. The extension tab was grayed out.

Comment: Please provide an image of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the sidebar to present the appropriate selector list based on the user request of 'add' versus 'update'.

Qn the server side: used the .append to send the information to the client side.

```
var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('foodOptions');
  var data = "add";
    var strAppend = "<div id='id_for_div' style='display:none;'>" + data + "</div>";
    form.append(strAppend);
```

On the client side: retrieved the information via

```
<body onload="getInformation();">
```

This was used in the javascript to display the appropriate options based on user request.

Thanks